# How to make this widget in flutter, which has an inbuilt widget at the end of the pointer as well?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]so there is an image in the end of every circle, and this progress indicator marks the progress within 100 percent, so the colour of each progress indicator is supposed to be dynamic, with an image at the end of the colour, as stated in the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this using custom painter :

https://github.com/NehaKushwah993/Flutter-Multi-Circle-Progress

[image]

Comment: use main.dart file added in the project.